# Instead of li, it's child is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list here:

```
<ul id="orderlist">
    <li id="2">
      <span class="pull-right value">Ready</span>
      <img src="" class="img-responsive"> Filet Mignon 
      <small>2 servings</small>
      <small>Note: No lettuce </small>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
      <span class="pull-right value">In Progress</span>
       <img src=""  class="img-responsive"> Tarte Tatin
      <small>2 servings</small>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

And I have a JavaScript for clicking each `li`:

```
$("body").on("click", "#orderedlist li", function(e) {
    $contextMenu.css({
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    oiID = $(e.target).attr('id');
    return false;
});
```

It works, but if I click the `<img>` or other elements inside the `li`, it returns `undefined` for `oiID` because it gets the child element not the `li`. How can I fix this that even if I click in the elements inside the parent, `li` should be the one recognized.

Comment: I don't see `orderedlist` defined anywhere in your HTML

Comment: $("body").on("click", "#orderedlist li", function(e) {

Comment: I believe Mr. Alien is referring to the fact that your snippet has the id as "orderlist", not "order **ed** list"

Comment: oh i see, but that's not the problem. just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$(e.target)` use `$(this)`.

```
oiID = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using JQuery, so use $(this):

```
oiID = $(this).attr('id');

// OR

oiID = $(e.target).attr('id');
if(oiID == '')
  oiID = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');
```